# Variable not being processed in the if condition .Bash script

Tags: shell-script

I have a simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
Result =$(zgrep -i "blocked session" /BACKUP/server.log.2019-06-23-06.gz | wc -l)

if [[ "$Result" -ge 1 ]];
 then
   echo "CRITICAL : The error string is found $Result times in server.log  file"
   exit 2
else
   echo "OK: No instances of the error string in the server.log file "
   exit 0
fi
```

There is about 1744 instances of the error string which the wc -l captures correctly but not being used in the if condition and I am getting an incorrect exit code

```
++ zgrep -i "blocked session" /BACKUP/server.log.2019-06-23-06.gz
++ wc -l
+ Result =1744
/tmp/test.sh: line 4: Result: command not found
+ [[ '' -ge 1 ]]
+ echo OK: No instances of the error string in the server.log file '
OK: echo "OK: No instances of the error string in the server.log file 
+ exit 0
```

Please let me know what i am missing here.

Comment: You have a space before `=`

Comment: Use https://shellcheck.net to pick up errors like this.

Comment: Your code shown here doesn't correspond to the code you ran. Otherwise the error message would have pointed to line 2 instead of line 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space from second line:

```
Result=$(zgrep -i "blocked session" /BACKUP/server.log.2019-06-23-06.gz | wc -l)
```

instead of

```
Result =$(zgrep -i "blocked session" /BACKUP/server.log.2019-06-23-06.gz | wc -l)
```

Comment: Thank you Bart, that did the trick.